# Jdk8 , using 'getDeclaredMethod' prompt 'NoSuchMethodException', but using 'getDeclaredMethods' is ok. Why?

Tags: reflection, java-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Rl3.png)

- code as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(ThreadLocalRandom.class.getName());

        Method advanceProbe = Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(item -> item.getName().contains("advanceProbe")).findFirst().get();
        System.out.println("advanceProbe = " + advanceProbe);

        Method advanceProbe2 = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("advanceProbe");// line: 15 
        System.out.println("advanceProbe2 = " + advanceProbe2);
    }
```

- result as follows

```
advanceProbe = static final int java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.advanceProbe(int)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.advanceProbe()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
    at util.concurrent.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Jdk8 , using 'getDeclaredMethod' prompt 'NoSuchMethodException', but using 'getDeclaredMethods'  is ok. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation for [`getDeclaredMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-). It expects the parameter types of the method that you are trying to find, in addition to the method name. If you don't include any parameter types, it will try to find a parameterless method with that name.

After all, how would `getDeclaredMethod` handle multiple methods with the same name otherwise? You need to give it the parameter types for it to distinguish between overloads.

There is no overload of `advanceProbe` that takes no parameters. That's why no method was found.

The method you are trying to find takes an `int` parameter, so you should do:

```
Method advanceProbe2 = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("advanceProbe", int.class);
```

Comment: understand,  
you are right, thanks